# Intel HAXM Ver. Not compatible

Tags: react-native, android-sdk-manager

Somehow my Android SDK manager package does not allow me to install HAXM V.6.0.5 on my Windows OS.8.1.

It says "not compatible". How do I install it? Or a version lower than the one which is compatible with my OS?

[image: My Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

you can install HAXM manualy from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

It should solve your problem if your system meets it's hardware requirements:

1) Intel processor with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality

2) At least 4 GB of available RAM, 8 GB recommended